# How to close preferences dialog boxes on OS X in eclipse using keyboard

Tags: eclipse, macos, dialog

Apparently eclipse does not respect standard os x Command-W to close the dialog boxes.  We are required to use the mouse to click on the red box in upper left of the dialog window. Has anyone figured out a keyboard-activated fix for this?

Comment: yes it does, i also found out command<dot> works

Comment: You must have your keybindings set up funny.  CMD+W works for me and CMD+. does not.

Comment: Only changes i have made to key bindings are the "witch" windows switcher and "Make Caps Lock another Command button".